# Simplest way to access internal resources in a K3S installation

Tags: kubernetes, networking, k3s

To preface: I know this is a bit of duplicate (this question has been asked many times here in different versions) but I can't really find a clear answer for how this is handled on bare metal.

The issue: I want to be able to access internal services without needing to port forward for each one. Like accessing loki or traefik dashboard. The setup is running standard K3S on a bare metal server. Most of the answers and guides focus on cloud based load balancers, but obviously that option isn't available to me.

There seems to be a number of ways to tackle this problem, but what is the absolute simplest? A second ingress controller that binds to the VPN interface? A loadbalancer (which one?)

I would really appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to expose a `k3s` service on your host is just to create a `LoadBalancer` service. You don't actually need to install a load balancer of any sort; this will expose your service ports on your host.

For example, start a pod:

```
k3s kubectl run --image docker.io/alpinelinux/darkhttpd:latest --port 8080 webtest
```

Create a service:

```
k3s kubectl expose pod webtest --target-port 8080 --name webtest --type=LoadBalancer
```

That gets us a manifest that looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: webtest
  name: webtest
  namespace: default
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.43.234.34
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.43.234.34
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31647
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: webtest
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 192.168.122.136
```

And now on my `k3s` host, I can:

```
$ curl localhost:8080
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
...
```

Or from somewhere else on my network:

```
$ curl 192.168.1212.136:8080
<html>
<head>
 <title>/</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the issue was with how traffic from my wireguard interface was being routed to k3s. After fixing the routes, I am able to access exposed services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).